# Ionic V4 (angular) content.scrollToTop

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

In Ionic V3.X, this would scroll view to top:

```
@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

this.content.scrollToTop();
```

In Ionic V4, this no longer works - 'Property scrollToTop does not exist on type Content'.

Is there an alternative? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the `scrollToTop()` method was added in **[v4.0.0-beta.3](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases/tag/v4.0.0-beta.3)** but some [issues](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/commit/695abcf) were fixed a few hours ago in **[v4.0.0-beta.6](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases/tag/v4.0.0-beta.6)**, so please update Ionic to the *beta.6* version and the `scrollToTop()` method should be available there.

**EDIT**:

> Thanks, but I'm already on V4.0.0-beta.6. Checking API, clearly there
>   is no scrollToTop() anymore.

I'm sorry to insist, but I've just installed V4.0.0-beta.6 and I'm able to use the `scrollToTop()` method without any problems:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already on V4.0.0-beta.6. Checking API, clearly there is no scrollToTop() anymore.

Comment: Hi @LarryKing, I've updated the answer. Could you please check when you have some time?

Comment: you are absolutely correct. Thank you very much for your insistence!! I upgraded to beta.6 from beta.1 two days ago, but my IDE was still giving me an error along the lines of 'scrollToTop' does not exist on type content. After seeing your demo, I actually looked at my app running again and in fact scrollToTop was working even with the IDE error - much to my surprise and pleasure! I just got hung up on the IDE error. Restarting my IDE fixed the error it was giving me, so all is good. Thank you again. :)

Comment: So glad to hear that it helped @LarryKing :)

Comment: I'm using v4 RC.1, it looks like it has been removed.

Comment: @Lance but it's included in the [content API docs](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/content/#methods).

Comment: @sebaferreras - I know. I looked into the source code, it's no longer there, and the intellisense from VS Code doesn't recognize it as well.

Comment: Can anyone confirm if this is working / not working please? I am sunning Ionic 4.6.0. I am getting a "has no exported member" error when importing "Content" from "@ionic/angular'

Comment: Ok I managed to sole the compiler error importing "IonContent" instead of "Content". No errors, but it is not performing the scroll action

Comment: @phunder could you please try with `this.content.getScrollElement().scrollToTop(duration)` as suggested [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/14793#issuecomment-411371712)? This is quite strange though since it seems the method is available in the [source code](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/content/content.tsx#L184)

Comment: @sebaferreras thank you kindly for the link. It however shows a compiler error saying "Property 'scrollToTop' does not exist on type 'Promise<HTMLElement>'"

Comment: @phunder I was able to make it work on my end by importing it like this `import { IonContent } from '@ionic/angular';`, then getting the reference 
 doing: `@ViewChild(IonContent) content: IonContent;` and then calling the method like this: `this.content.scrollToTop(500);`.

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
@ViewChild(IonContent) content: IonContent;

...

this.content.scrollToTop(500);
```

It works for me, hope it will help you too. For more details https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-how-to-scroll-to-top-bottom-using-ion-content-scroll-events/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;   
this.content.scrollTop=0;
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxxrfp

Comment: Thank you. Yes, for sure this is working in Angular: when I take your stackblitz & modify with `@ViewChild('container') container: ElementRef;` and either `this.container.nativeElement.scrollTop = 0;` or `this.container.nativeElement.scrollTo(0, 0);` all is fine. But when I do same in Ionic V4 it does not work. Seems like something in @ionic/angular maybe?